# Issue with parse.com login routine

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, parse-platform

I created an extra field in the parse.com back end in the user table and I called it deviceId. Now in parse documentation it says to reference the field as per below but when i do i get an exception saying that the Context Key does not exsit.

```
private async  void btnSignUp_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

      var user = new ParseUser()
    {
        Username = txtusername.Text,
        Password = txtPassword.Text,
        Email = txtEmail.Text

    };
/// add the phones device id into the extra column created 

        user["deviceid"] = _curoHelpers.GetWinodwsPhoneDeviceId();

        await user.SignUpAsync();

}
```

When i Debug the key is indead not their is this yet again another bug due to parse?

[image]

Here is the parse screen shot just to prove I am adding column to back end

[image]

Parse is a great platform but infuriating with the small bugs.

Comment: You should be contacting their support about this.

Comment: @Will parse.com on here is their support tag they advise posting to here first !

Comment: Not for bug reports.  We only accept practical, answerable programming questions.  You've well proved that you should have that key in the dictionary.  If it isn't there, and this is because of "the small bugs" as you suggest, then you need to contact parse.com support so they can *fix the bug*.

Comment: @Will I am not sure if its a bug , this is the first port of call to see if its a bug first to see if any users are expierence the same ! and the context of the small bugs is on the paltform in a whole not this particualr item I have posted!

Comment: I think you'd do better contacting parse support.  Good luck.

Comment: @Will its alsmot none existent dude as soon as bought over by facebook they forget about the little people who make their platform pouplar thanks for understand I no we here to keep stack right im a long time developer mate

Comment: I believe Parse supports adding data to columns even if they don't exist... my guess is that the issue is that you're using ParseUser and not ParseObject. Try with ParseObject and give the users table name in the constructor and see if it works. If that doesn't work, then my second guess is that their users table is a special table. If that's the case you can workaround it by creating a different table with your deviceid and a foreign key to their users table.

Comment: @tzachs that is odd cause documentation states this https://parse.com/docs/dotnet/guide#users-signing-up

Comment: You're right, it is odd.. I'd try it regardless if I were you (unless you can get their support).

Comment: @tzachs parse had a DOD attack yesterday their dennying it but their service went into recovery mode causing it to read only stanadard objects